# Can a holomorphic function satisfy f(1/n)=n/(n+2)?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a function $f$ holomorphic in $|z|<1$ that satisfies $f\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\right)=\displaystyle\frac{n}{n+2}$? I have been trying to create a proof using the uniqueness/identity theorem but only obtain $f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+2z}$ which appears to not be holomorphic in $|z|<1$ because of the singularity at $z=-\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$. Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if the identity theorem tells you that $f(z) = 1/(1+2z)$ is the only possible $f$, and that $f$ is not holomorphic in $|z| < 1$, what can you conclude?